# Does M2 have Recurring Profile?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, recurring

As per the [v2.2.2 CHANGELOG](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/CHANGELOG.md), M2 has removed the **Recurring Profile** feature in [0.1.0-alpha108](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/CHANGELOG.md#010-alpha108) version as mentioned under **Various improvements** section.

However, if you look at the changes in [2.0.0.0-dev65](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/CHANGELOG.md#2000-dev65) version, it says that **Recurring Profile** has moved to a separate module as mentioned under **Modularity improvements** section, but there is no such module.

So does M2 have the Recurring Profile feature or planning to have in the future releases?

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 has the Recurring Profile module in the [offcial github codes](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/0.1.0-alpha106/app/code/Magento/RecurringPayment), but it has not been developed for **five years**.

I think this feature has been abandoned by offcial, we have to implement this feature with other third party module.

[image]